# JQuery template: how to access newly created option items in jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have the following JSON array that I need to iterate through and create HTML option items using JQuery template. The problem I have is the data might have duplicate values for within each group. As shown below `a`can be repeated in both groups.

```
"groups":[{//group one
        "names" : {
            "a" : "name1",
            "b" : "name2",
        }
    }, { //group two
        "names" : {
            "a" : "name1"
        }
    }//...
]
```

This is how I am trying to add to the options using JQuery template.

```
<select id="select1" >
    {{each(groupIndex, group) ResponseData.groups}}
        {{each(index, name) group}}
            <option value="${name}" >${index}</option>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}   
</select>
```

But this will add `a` twice as an option.

Is there any way to access the select element using the ID `select1` and check if an option with value `a` already added using JQuery template?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to preprocess json into an array with unique values
and the use them in jquery template.